# Make request to REST services when HTML services are blocked

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-rest-api, getcapabilities

Is there a way to request ArcGIS REST services when HTTP access is blocked?

> error 403 forbidden access

I was using Python to get the data from the ArcGIS MapServer but they blocked HTTP access so now I can't.

Comment: HTTPS has pretty much replaced HTTP for most use cases (and it eliminates mixed protocol issues). If ports 80/8080 are blocked at the source, you'll need to provide a pretty compelling reason to get them unlocked.

Comment: REST doesn't need HTTP

Comment: They are isnpire gov data that should have been accessible according to eu, I don't know why they did it. It's https, is there an other way to access the map service data?